# How to connect to a remote tomcat with Netbeans?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

On a Windows Server 2008 R2 I have installed tomcat, and I have opened the port from the firewall. How can I connect to the Tomcat server with Netbans from my PC?

I want to run a web project from my PC and a servlet run on the remote tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans needs his own tomcat. There are hard tricks existing to connect a tomcat which it doesn't own, but they even needs tomcat to run on the same machine.

I'm really sorry for this, too. It remembers me to the sucks with windows3.0 in 1992.